# Why do i get this node.js build error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I'm trying to build my project using browserify, (the local binary from `node_modules/.bin/`)

this is the complete command

`./node_modules/.bin/browserify . | uglifyjs -cm >js/bundle.min.js`

my directory is `/var/www/react-shopping`

I do not understand this error,  `Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/react-shopping'`

Complete error here,

```
Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/react-shopping' from '/var/www/react-shopping'
    at /var/www/react-shopping/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:55:21
    at load (/var/www/react-shopping/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
    at onex (/var/www/react-shopping/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
    at /var/www/react-shopping/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

Comment: Try running as sudo?

Comment: @BrooklynWebDevelopers Exact same error again

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
browserify index.js | uglifyjs -cm > js/bundle.min.js
```

where `index.js` is the entry point of your application.

`browserify` should be installed with:

```
npm install --save-dev browserify
```

and `uglifyjs` with:

```
npm install --save-dev uglifyify
```

[Take a look at this for more information](https://github.com/hughsk/uglifyify)

Comment: This doesn't really explain anything about the problem, unfortunately.